# Como adicionar nuevos metodos

Tags: laravel-5

Buen dia

En el momento estoy usando un controlador tipo `route::resouce`, como bien saben este agrega cierto métodos para facilitar el trabajo, como `index, create, edit, destroy`.
El problema que presento es que agregue un método personalizado.

```
  public function lista()

   {
        $tipos_usuarios = \DB::table('tipos_usuarios')
                             ->select('id', 'usuarios_rol')
                             ->get();
        return view('auth.register')->with('tipos_usuarios', $tipos_usuarios);
    }
```

Pero por alguna razon, el controlador no lee mi nuevo metodo, acaso hay que configurarlo en la raiz de laravel, pera que sea reconocido?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El controlador de tipo *resource* se crea con el siguiente comando

```
php artisan make:controller BlogController --resource
```

Posteriormente a nivel de rutas lo usamos del modo siguiente

```
Route::resource('/saludo', 'BlogController');
```

El Controlador anterior `BlogController`, posee los métodos:

1. destroy
2. update
3. edit
4. show
5. store
6. create
7. index

Sin embargo ahora voy a declarar un nuevo método llamado `sayHi()` del modo siguiente (*este método no pertenece a la lsita de verbos HTTP regulares*)

```
 public function sayHi()
 {
     return "Hola a todos y todas";
 }
```

**¿Cómo lo llamo ahora?**

Simplemente identifica el verbo HTTP que requiere y genera su nueva ruta, justo antes de la llamada al `Route::resource`

Debería quedar así

```
Route::get('/saludos', 'BlogController@sayHi');
Route::resource('/saludo', 'BlogController');
```

**Observaciones**

> 1. El llamado al método personalizado, es decir el que tu creas debe ir al inicio
> 2. el controlador ocupado es el mismo pero al final con el marcador `@` apuntamos al nombre del método que deseamos invocar

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo